# "frm-40010" on "windows 10" oracle forms 6.0 frm-40010: cannot read from app_user

Tags: windows, oracle, oracleforms

Please help me to run oracle app on windows 10 64bit or 32bit,
I always get this error.

oracle forms 6.0
frm-40010: cannot read from app_user

its work on win7 32bit normal, but win10 32/64 bit never run.

so what the trick to fix it?

windows 10 but nothing
I need to run it on windows 10 32 or 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms 6i is really ancient; the last certified and supported MS Windows operating version was **XP**.

If you need to run that application on Windows 10, consider installing a **virtual machine** that runs under Windows XP, put Forms 6i there and you should be using it with no problems.